# How to share my Test Class with another my cpp files?

Tags: c++

```
class Test
{
public:
    HANDLE TestHandle

    Test(LPCSTR Path)
    {
        TestHandle = CreateFileA(Path, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    }

    DWORD TestFunc()
    {
        printf("I'm Banana~!")
        return 0;
    }
}
```

a simple code,

i hope to know how to share my TestHandle?

```
int main()
{
    Test TestVariable = Test("C:\ABCD\");
    Test.TestFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

this code is work, but i hope to do this

> main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    TestVariable = Test("C:\ABCD\");

    while (true)
    {   
        // it's just loop code, don't think about this.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> efficient.cpp

```
void Tester()
{
    TestVariable.TestFunc();
}
```

plz help me :)
i hope to share my class on my header files for using them with another my cpp files
but it should be declared in int main() code.

Comment: This will teach you how : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-files/. After that compile all the cpp files and link them

Answer (score 0):

You should divide your project into header files(*.h,.hpp* etc) and source files(*.cpp*). One example to get you started is shown below:

**test.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class Test
{
    public:

        Test(std::string pName);//this is a declaration
        int TestFunc(); //this is a declaration
    
    private:
        std::string name;
};
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

//define the constructor
Test::Test(std::string pname): name(pname)
{
   std::cout<<"Constructor called"<<std::endl;
}

//define member function TestFunc
int Test::TestFunc()
{
    std::cout<<"TestFunc called"<<std::endl;
    return 5;
}
```

**efficient.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "test.h"

//This function takes an object of type Test by reference
void Tester(Test& TestVariable);//this is a declaration
```

**efficient.cpp**

```
#include "efficient.h"
#include <iostream>

//define Tester
void Tester(Test& TestVariable)
{
    std::cout<<"Tester called"<<std::endl;
    TestVariable.TestFunc();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "efficient.h"
int main()
{
    //create object of type Test 
    Test TestVariable("C:D:A");

    //call Tester function 
    Tester(TestVariable);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/hyEuhISUp).